# Handling behavior of browser back button in MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, browser, view

I have this scenario:

- I'm in ANY **View** of the application, then I go to **google.com** by typing it in
  browser.
- I want to return to my View, so I press the back button of the browser.
- I'm back to my **View**.
- One second later browser  automatically redirect me back to **google.com**

If I click back button is because I want to go to my View, not stay in Google.

How could I handle this behavior?

Comment: This isn't the normal view of an MVC application. It's likely something in your own code. Can you create a very simple view that exhibits the behavior and post the code of that view?

Comment: Just found this code in the layout file: <script> function disableBackButton() { window.history.forward(); } setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0); </script>. You think this is the problem? @EricJ.

Comment: Yes that code is doing it. Every time you hit the back button, that code runs and moves you right back where you were. In general, it's not a very good idea to change the behavior of the browser.

Comment: Whoa, thanks, it was in the layout, thats why I couldn't find it. I searched in code, web.config, global, etc. When I was creating the simple view I realized that it would be in the layout. Was hard to find because I don't started this proyect, just making maintenance @EricJ.